# How to make a variable available to all of the TaskManagers in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I need to set a list of values in my program and access them in all of the task managers. Currently, I declared a public field in my main class and set the values. Later in my program, which will be run in a remote cluster, I would like to have access to this variables in all task managers.
Here is my sample code. It seems there is a problem however: there is not any compile or run-time error, the values are not available to the task managers.

```java
public class myMainClass {
  public static ArrayList<String> mykey =  new ArrayList<String>();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // assign value to the variable
    partitionedData = partitionedData.partitionCustom(new MyPartitioner(myKey), 2);
  }
}

public static class MyPartitioner implements Partitioner<String> {
 public String [] partitionKeys;
public static ArrayList<String> mykey;
 public MyPartitioner(ArrayList<String> mykey) {
        this.mykey = mykey;
    }

  @Override
  public int partition(String key, int numPartitions) {
    for (int i=0 ; i< numParalell-1 ; i++) {
      if(mykey.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(key) > 0)
        return i;
    }

    return numParalell-1 ;              
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your `mykey` field in `MyPartitioner` is declared `static`. This will not be serialized and therefore, I expect, the data will not be available on the cluster.

The same applies, by the way, to using a static field of your main class. This data will also not be available on the cluster.

Comment: You are right, the problem was that, Thank you!

Comment: this is my failed job ,could you give me a hand ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489846/flink-slot-memory-leak-after-restarting-job-with-static-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass the `mykey` list as an constructor argument to the `MyPartitioner` class.

Your code would look like this:

```java
public class myMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> mykey =  new ArrayList<String>();
        // assign value to the vaiable
        partitionedData = partitionedData.partitionCustom(new MyPartitioner(mykey), 2);
    }
}

public static class MyPartitioner implements Partitioner<String> {
    private final ArrayList<String> mykey;
    public String [] partitionKeys;

    public MyPartitioner(ArrayList<String> mykey) {
        this.mykey = mykey;
    }

    @Override
    public int partition(String key, int numPartitions) {
        for (int i=0 ; i< numParalell-1 ; i++) {
            if(mykey.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(key) > 0)
                return i;
        }

        return numParalell-1 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already did the same but unfortunately it did not resolve my problem. The solution works if I run program on a local cluster but not on the remote cluster.

Comment: In the code example in the original question, I can not see where you populate the list with data. 
Is it before the execute() call? Are you changing the list at runtime?

Comment: the list gets value before calling partitioner, exactly the line // assign value to the variable. After that a print command shows that values as it is expected.

Comment: Can you try it again with the closure cleaner disabled? `env.getConfig().disableClosureCleaner()`

Comment: Did that resolve the problem (I'm wondering because you've marked my answer as the correct answer)?

Comment: Looking at the issue again, I don't think that the closure cleaner is the problem. The `mykey` field is static in the `MyPartitioner` class. Making it non-static should actually resolve the issue.

Comment: Your are right, comparing to your code I found the bug is: I defined the myKey Static. So removing that resolved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to accomplish. If you want to pre-compute a (non-changing) value and distribute it to all task managers (I assume you need access those value in some operators), you can simple give those value via constructor parameters to your UDFs or use Flink's broadcast variables: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.8/programming_guide.html#broadcast-variables

Comment: As you said, I want to use a pre-computed values to do a custom partitioning. I already used a constructor to pass the value as mentioned in the link but it does not seem to produce correct result.

Comment: Can you update your code example to the new version? Did you do it the way @rmetzeger suggested? Furthermore, can you describe in more detail what you expected and actual behavior is?

Comment: What happens when you run your code in remote cluster? What behavior do you get? What behavior do you expect? What is the concrete problem? What does "the values are not available to the task managers" mean? Is "mykey" an empty list (As you mentioned that there are no errors, I would assume that is is not "null").

Comment: I expect to partition data based on the values in the variable passed into the partitioner. It works fine if I run the program in a local cluster. If I run it on a remote cluster using the same dataset it does not do partitioning and all of the data is passed into just one node.

Comment: Btw: In your code example, do you mean `numPartitions` instead of `numParalell` ?? Can you log `myKeys` to see it's content? Right now, it seems that it's an empty list -- if this is true, I assume you hit a bug in Flink...

Comment: Could you please let me know how to log myKeys?

Comment: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.7/internal_logging.html Or just do printf-debugging... sys-out will be redirected into "*.out" files. The log and out files are located in log folder on each TaskManager machine.

Comment: Considering a minor change in the code as follows, I get the null exception in the line of code which accessing the variable myKey.                                                                                                 public int partition(String key, int numPartitions) {
        for (int i=0 ; i< numPartitions-1 ; i++) {
            if(mykey.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(key) > 0)
                return i;
        }

        return numPartitions-1 ;
    }